# xpath to return single node of array

Tags: xml, testing, xpath, automated-tests, web-testing

The question is will it be possible to filter the array of nodes in the Xpath itself.

Example, while web automation there is a column to select the row. now I have the xpath to filter for the column but it still is an array and I would like filter it out to a single element.

```
//td[<expr> and <array offset>]
```

I believe the following is wrong

```
//td[<expr>][<array offset>]
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: xml or html example would help

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```
(//td[<expr>])[<array offset>]
```